# Why multiple requests to socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

After well connected, client side automatically starts and continious sending multiple request everytime to socket.io (this occurs only when running remote server,  but in localhost works as espected)

Is it normal behaviour or what is the problem?

```
XHR?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N-as6a7&sid=t2sQ_wVWxcst5FIBAACS  
XHR?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N-as6pm&sid=t2sQ_wVWxcst5FIBAACS  
XHR?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N-as73Q&sid=t2sQ_wVWxcst5FIBAACS  
XHR?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N-as7J4&sid=t2sQ_wVWxcst5FIBAACS  
XHR?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N-as7Yc&sid=t2sQ_wVWxcst5FIBAACS  
XHR?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N-as7oF&sid=t2sQ_wVWxcst5FIBAACS  
...



00:27:05.081    200 755 583 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    597 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:05.681    200 755 583 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    350 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:06.035    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    984 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:07.022    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    997 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:08.020    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    997 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:09.019    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    1025 ms 
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:10.046    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    973 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:11.021    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    996 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:12.019    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    998 ms  
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
00:27:13.019    200 755 582 [Text][OK][CACHE ??]    1008 ms 
GET https://maxmoney.app/socket.io/
```

...